# Control all urls from domain-root's index.php

Tags: php

**The result I wanted:**

A user visits https://example.com/dir-one/dir-two/file.php
But there is neither dir-one nor dir-two in main folder.
But the browser show them the content described in /user/public_html/index.php (which shows as https://example.com/index.php)
I imagined this code example for https://example.com/dir-one/dir-two/file.php

```
<?php
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // "/dir-one/dir-two/file.php"
if($uri == "/dirone/"){echo "you are in first dir i.e. dirone";}
if($uri == "/dirone/dirtwo/"){echo "you are in second dir i.e. dirtwo in dirone";}
if($uri == "/dirone/dirtwo/file.php"){echo "you are at file in second dir i.e. dirtwo in dirone";}
?>
```

Result:

```
you are at file in second dir i.e. dirtwo in dirone"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a router.

See [this](https://www.taniarascia.com/the-simplest-php-router/)